# How change UIactionsheet to Popover?

Tags: ios, popover, uiactionsheet

Use this code to open an actionsheet.
On iPhone works perfectly, but on iPad it crashes. I think it's because of arm64. Probably I have to transform Actionsheet into a popover.

How do I change this code?

```
- (void)pushedNewBtn
{
    UIActionSheet *sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Camera", @"Photo Library", nil];
    [sheet showInView:self.view.window];
}
```

Comment: `UIActionSheet` is deprecated. You should be using `UIAlertController` unless you need to support iOS 7.

Comment: BTW - when you post a question about a crash you need to include details about the crash in your question. Please update your question with those details.

Answer (score 1):

For the correct use of `UIAlertView`s you need to use the delegate methods to respond to a button being pressed.
In your header file you need the following
`@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>`

You have correctly set the delegate of your `UIAlertView` variable using the following line `delegate:self`.

Now, once you press a button in the `UIAlertView`, the delegate will call the following method

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

You can then respond to button presses in there with code that looks something similar to this

```
switch (buttonIndex) {
    case 0:
        //Cancel button code goes here if needed
        break;
    case 1:
        //First 'other' button code goes here
        break;
    case 2:
        //second 'other' button code goes here
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: If this has answered your question, then please mark it as the accepted answer with the tick. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

this is the working result:

```
 - (void)pushedNewBtn {
    UIAlertView *sheet = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Camera", @"Photo Library", nil];
    [sheet show];
}

- (void)libraryButton {
    UIImagePickerController *pickerLibrary = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    pickerLibrary.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    pickerLibrary.delegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:pickerLibrary animated:YES];

}

- (void)cameraButton {
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
 }

#pragma mark- alertView delegate PICKER


- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    switch (buttonIndex) {

        case 0:
            return;
            break;
        case 1:
            [self cameraButton];
            break;
        case 2:
            [self libraryButton];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

but now i have new problem,
I want to INSERT A New alertviev but does not work

```
    - (void)pushedSaveBtn {

    UIAlertView *sheet2 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Save", nil];
    [sheet2 show];
}

- (void)savemeButton {

   //codice da inserire
}

#pragma mark- alertView2 delegate SAVER


- (void)alertView2:(UIAlertView *)alertView2 clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    switch (buttonIndex) {

        case 0:
            return;
            break;
        case 1:
            [self savemeButton];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a separate question. You should make a new one. The answer is set the tag of your alert and in the `clickedButtonAtIndex` method put in an `if` command to check what the tag of the incoming alertview is